# FFT frequency of sound

Tags: c#, .net, fft, naudio

On microphone at some time, starts flowing sound defined frequency(500hz). How do I know when the signal began to come to the microphone? To solve this problem, I know that I need to use FFT(Fast Fourier transform). But I dont understand, how should I take after FFT frequency? I'm use NAudio on C#. And my buffer from microphone is byte array.

Comment: If you're strictly interested in 500 Hz tones you could also use autocorellation, which is easier to grasp for most people. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

Answer (score 2):

Using an FFT for this is overkill and not particularly appropriate. A much simpler solution for this kind of problem (tone detection/onset detection) is the [Goertzel filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Determining WHEN a signal is sampled into a buffer is a programatical problem.

That has nothing to do with determining WHAT the frequency content of the sampled signal is (using the FFT). See my reply for your other question...

Answer (score 1):

A narrow IIR bandpass filter followed by an envelope detector might be one possible method to try.  Another thing to try might be cross-correlation against a matched filter, if you know the rise time of your tone burst.  You will have to calibrate out the latency of your audio input signal path as well.