# The code is not detecting the desired frequency of audio sound

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I am trying to write a code using NAudio which detects the desired frequency. For example, my code should be able to say whether the sound of frequency 20100 Hz(Yes ultrasonic is the basic requirement) is getting emitted or not. Basically, I am reading all the int values from the NAudio WaveInEvent of NAudio and apply FFT on a chunk of it(2018) values. I get the index of the desired frequency and then check for it in the FFT sample.

For FFT, I am using `MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms`. Applying FFT will give me complex values to which I apply `abs` and then I multiply by the sampling rate and divide by datasize to get frq.

I get the index by

```
private int getIndex(int freq) {
    return (int)Math.Round((freq/44100d)*2018d);
}
index = getIndex(20100);
```

Receive code

```
public void OnFramesArrivedEvent(object sender , EventArgs args) {
   Complex[] sound_data = new Complex[sound.Count];
   for (int i = 0; i< sound.Count; i++) {
       sound_data[i] = sound[i];
   }

   Fourier.Forward(sound_data);

   for (int i = index-1; i<index+3; i++ ) {
       try
       {
           int xx = (int)(((Soundabs(sound_data[i])) * 44100) / 2018);
           //if (Math.Abs(xx - 20100) < 500)
           //{
           //    Console.WriteLine(xx);
           //}
           Console.WriteLine(xx);
       }
       catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ie) {
           Console.WriteLine("------" + i);
       }

   }
   sound.Clear();
}
```

To get absolute value of an FFT Complex num i use

```
public double Soundabs(Complex num)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(num.Real * num.Real + num.Imaginary * num.Imaginary);
    //return Complex.Abs(num);
}
```

Code is not detecting frequency . Instead ,it is detecting other frequencies . 
I used multiple ways to generate frequency , and it is not working .

Comment: How are you receiving these ultrasonic noises? You are aware that many consumer sound cards cut off sharply at high frequencies, right? https://www.reddit.com/r/Acoustics/comments/7b7up6/sound_cards_for_ultrasonic_frequencies/

Comment: Can you plot the source data and the FFT data? It's hard to say what's not working without seeing them.

Comment: Its a very valid point Ian Mercer . But code is not working even for audible frequencies like 352Hz. If they have such filters, is there a way around that. Meaning , is there a way that i can send a command to sound card not to apply those filters .

Comment: When you say 'apply FFT on a chunk of it(2018) values', do you mean you're doing FFT on 2018 samples? Sample size is generally an integral power of 2....

Comment: Oh . I am applying FFt on 2018 . I will make it as power of 2 and check it .

Comment: Also see other suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13010141/83202